# When to use Azure blob storage versus Azure file share?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

Azure newbie here.
I have an architecture requirement to move the data from on-premise to cloud database. This is done in two steps due to security restrictions and timelines.

1. Move the file to azure blob storage
2. Read from the blob and Import to the sql database .

Azure blob is suggested for unstructured data. However, the data we want to export to cloud is a simple export of data from sql tables to csv  files.

For such requirements what is recommended? Azure blob or Azure file share? When to use blob versus azure file share ?

Comment: See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/windowsazurestorage/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service#when-to-use-azure-files-vs-azure-blobs-vs-azure-disks. HTH.

Comment: There's an Azure service that does exactly what you want without you having to export to temporary storage - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/database-migration/

Comment: Hello MBK, welcome to Stack Overflow. If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you want to migrate database from local/on-premise SQL Server to Azure SQL, there are many ways can help do that directly without Blob or File Storage.

Such as:

1. Using [Data Migration Assistant(DMA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to help you migrate the data/database to Azure.

   Ref: [Migrate on-premises SQL Server or SQL Server on Azure VMs to Azure SQL Database using the Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateonpremsqltosqldb?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) task: Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database.

   [image]

   Ref: [Using the Deploy Database to SQL Azure Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio to move to the Cloud](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3035/using-the-deploy-database-to-sql-azure-wizard-in-sql-server-management-studio-to-move-to-the-cloud/)

Of course you could export the sql server data as CSV files to Blob or File storage, then import the csv file to Azure SQL. In usually, we often use Blob Storage work with Azure SQL database. It's up to you, reference the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/windowsazurestorage/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service#when-to-use-azure-files-vs-azure-blobs-vs-azure-disks) @Gaurav Mantri-AIS mentioned.

Hope this helps.